# How to count stairs in flutter application

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am trying to create application in flutter which would calculate stairs and steps if anyone know how to find logitude and altitude or some other helpful sensors related to my project kindly mention them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pedometer with Daily steps counter using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653412/pedometer-with-daily-steps-counter-using-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate just steps with `gyro` and `Accelerometer` but can not count stairs through sensors.